# "Use BabelJS / ES2015" on Code Snippet - tooltips needs to be with container "body"

Tags: bug, design, stack-snippets

If you create a code snippet, for ex. here in meta. If you hover over the "Use BabelJS / ES2015" right (i) icon, or the "Hide snippet by default" (i) icon. It shows a tooltip, but it seems the container of the tooltip is the left panel, so the text inside the tooltip is cropped.

[image: cropped text]

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFWM5.png) in Firefox 54.0a2.

Comment: oh... using chrome/osx last version of each one ( 58.0.3029.110 / 10.12.5 )

Comment: 15" monitor (maybe it look good in other resolutions?)

Comment: I don't think resolution is the issue. The tooltip is being covered up by the JS section of the snippet instead of appearing above it. Even if I make my browser window very small, the tooltip still appears on top of all other content.

Comment: data-container="body" should do it right? (they are using a custom tooltip thing)